# If `main` is an instance of `Object`, why can't I call it?

Tags: ruby

When I type `self`, I get a return value `main`. I made this test:

```
main2 = Object.new
```

Then I can call `main2`, and it returns something, but when I call `main`, it raises an undefined variable error. How does this happen?

Here's the assumption I found in other site about how this top level environment works:

```
class Object  
  Object.new.instance_eval do  
    def self.to_s  
      "main"  
    end  
   private  
    ##  
    # Your program gets inserted here...  
    ##  

  end  
end
```

It makes sense to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"[What is the Ruby Top-Level?](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/)" is an article on the Ruby top level that explains everything you need to know.

As an aside however, you can access `main` anywhere in your program by using `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('self')`.

Comment: what a great article you provide, it now totally makes sense, by the way I've learned #include Module.new, it's just a eye opener for me! Thanks again!

Comment: by the way the remove to_s from the singleton class of main is a great way to illustrate the whole structure! great!

Answer (score 4):

The evaluation of the expression `self` in irb does return an object that *prints* as main.  Here is a transcript that should help:

```
$ irb
>> self
=> main
>> main
NameError: undefined local variable or method `main' for main:Object
        from (irb):2
>> self.inspect
=> "main"
>> self.class
>> Object
```

When you type `main` into irb, it tries to evaluate the variable `main` which is not declared.

Comment: In addition, if you change `self.inspect` (to return `"foo"` for example), self will then return "foo"

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to the `main` object directly with something like

```
myvar = main
```

It's not possible to refer to it by its "name". However, you can capture it in a variable named main like this

```
main = self
puts main # => main
```

"[top-level object? top-level methods?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/7bb7b451a8f3cca7/98c4c62127b9d945?q=itsme213+main+singleton+Object&rnum=1#98c4c62127b9d945)" is useful background information on the main object by Ruby's inventor himself.

Comment: Now I now main is just a return value by to_s method of it's singleton class, The way that I can pass it to a variable is that remove the to_s from it's singleton class and the self return the real instance, and then I can pass it, that what I learned from @banister's article thanks for you guys