# How to test system calls from the rake task

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, system, stub

Suppose I have a pretty simple Rake task:

```
task :test do
  system "bundle exec rspec spec"
end
```

I try testing it by stubbing the `::Kernel.system` method call:

```
describe "test" do

  before { allow(::Kernel).to receive(:system) }

  it "runs 'bundle exec rspec spec'" do
    expect(::Kernel).to receive(:system).with "bundle exec rspec spec"
    Rake::Task[:test].invoke
  end
end
```

But the method seems not to be stubbed at all. Instead, I run into the infinite cycle of iterations calling the test suite.

What's wrong with it, and howto stub system calls properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `Kernel` is a module which is included into every ruby `Object`. And `Kernel#system` is an instance method (not a class method).

One solution (although [discouraged by rspec maintainers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)) is to use "Any instance":

```
it "runs 'bundle exec rspec spec'" do
  expect_any_instance_of(Kernel).to receive(:system).with "bundle exec rspec spec"
  Rake::Task[:test].invoke
end
```

In order to use regular `expect` or `allow`, you will need the actual **instance** of the object which is receiving the message. For a Rake task this will be cumbersome (although not impossible - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639141/if-main-is-an-instance-of-object-why-cant-i-call-it)) - they are executed in the toplevel context.

I would propose that you encapsulate your `system` calls into utility class methods and `expect` those. It would make the testing easier and you have explicit classes & instances to work with.

Comment: Thank you, Łukasz, you've saved my day!
With a new RSpec syntax I've totally forgotten this old syntax of 'any_instance'

For clarity, I'd just say that it is `allow_any_instance` that solves the problem.